# Python Calculator, return statemt

Tags: python

I've been trying to make a basic calculator in python in an attempt to learn it. I got a pretty good start at it but I don't know why this recursion function isn't returning a value.

```
def Difference(x=int, y=int, z=bool):
if y != 0:
    if z:
        if int(y) > 0:
            y -= 1
            x -= 1
            Difference(x, y, True)
        elif int(y) < 0:
            y += 1
            x += 1
            Difference(x, y, True)

    if not z:
        if int(y) > 0:
            y -= 1
            x += 1
            Difference(x, y, False)
        elif int(y) < 0:
            y += 1
            x -= 1
            Difference(x, y, False)
else:
    return int(x)

D = Difference(15,2,True)
```

If anyone can help out where it might be going wrong would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Missing return statement

Comment: you only have a return statement in the else, you need it above it as well

Comment: This does not do what you think it does: `def Difference(x=int, y=int, z=bool):`.  If you're trying to do type annotations, as I think you are, you want colons in there, not equals.  `def Difference(x: int, y: int, z: bool):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add "return" before every recursive call to "Difference(x, y, z)" in the function definition, as it is supposed to return something.

In python if you don't propagate/use the return statements of function calls it will be swallowed in the scope where it is called. As your code is meant for recursion you should propagate the return of the child recursive loop to the parent recursive loop, else it will be discarded and the execution continues returning None.